# recursive tree for the cutting Rod prob set

Tags: python, memory, recursion, dynamic

I have the a recursive solution to the cutting rod (dynamic problem). The problem is described [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/). 
If you run this code you notice that when the outer for loop iterates the recursive function doesn't run again (see 'i' doesn't get printed again for 0 and 1). I am wondering whether Python memorizes the result of the recursion from the previous iteration? I thought it would have to do the recursive call each time I iterate i, but it doesn't seem like it.

```
def cutRod(n, prices):
    if n <= 1:
        return prices[0]
    max_val = 0
    for i in range(n):
        print i, max_val
        max_val = max(max_val, prices[i] + cutRod(n-i-1, prices))
        print max_val
    return max_val

prices = [2,5,3]
n = len(prices)
print cutRod(n,prices)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct except changing 2nd line from `if n <= 1:` to `if n == 1:`, which will let the line `max_val = max(max_val, prices[i] + cutRod(n-i-1, prices))` work correctly when `i = n-1`. After this modification, if `i = n-1`, we have `cutRod(n-i-1, prices) = cutRod(n-(n-1)-1, price)) = cutRod(0, price) = 0` rather than `cutRod(0, price) = prices[0]` before modification. Actually, the recursive function run again in your code and `max_value` from the previous iteration can be memorized.